# Inserir dados aleatórios em uma tabela que tenha chaves estrangeiras (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Tenho uma tabela `"usuario" (idUsuario, nome, departamentoId)` e outra tabela `"departamento" (idDepartamento, nome)`.

Gostaria de inserir dados aleatórios na tabela usuário, mas para isso, preciso considerar apenas os IDs (FKs) dos departamentos que já foram inseridos.

Acho que deveria ser algo do tipo:

```
INSERT INTO usuario (idusuario, nome, departamentoId)
VALUES (seq_usuario.nextVal, 'nomealeatorio', FK_ALEATORIA_DEPARTAMENTO);
```

Como faço pra gerar esse 'nomealeatorio' e pegar uma FK de departamento que já exista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível consultar a tabela de departamentos e recuperar uma linha aleatória para adicionar ao registro.

Nesse [artigo](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm) ele explica como fazer isso em diversos bancos. No seu caso, usando Oracle, a query ficaria parecida com a seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO usuario(idUsuario, nome, departamentoId)
SELECT seq_usuario.nextVal, 'nomealeatorio', d.idDepartamento FROM
    ( SELECT idDepartamento FROM departamento d
    ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
    WHERE rownum = 1
```

Dessa forma, você irá inserir um registro na tabela de usuários com o sequencial desejado, o nome aleatório que você escolheu e um departamento aleatório existente na tabela de departamentos

Comment: Funcionou! Muitíssimo obrigado!

Abs.

Comment: Usando a package dbms_random, pode-se gerar, números e strings aleatórias, útil se precisar gerar "nomes" diferentes para algum teste.

Comment: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_random.php